# How to modify apalike.bst to remove the authorname bulleting?

Tags: bibtex

which part of apalike.bst do I have to change to remove authorname bulleting?

The references begins as "[Author, year] Author (year). Paper/Book title..." 
But I want it to begin as "Author (year) Paper/Book title...".

I want this formatting to apply for all entry types (@article, @book, etc).

Comment: Please provide a [minimal example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/8528) (or see [here](http://www.tex.ac.uk/cgi-bin/texfaq2html?label=minxampl)). I do not see this 'bulleting' by default.

Comment: Look also at [minimal working example with bibliography (MWEB)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/4407).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need to change anything in the `apalike` bibliography style. Just load the `natbib` package, and the material in square brackets will no longer show up in the typeset bibliography.

Comment: This is very simple to execute!